# Deploy flask to a single server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, deployment

Easy deployment of a Flask API, how do we do that? What is the best way?
I would like to deploy my Flask API on a single server, in the beginning. I just got started with a new project and I don't want to spend too much time on Docker and scalability. I am even a bit scared to use Docker in production at the beginning anyway.

With PHP there are a ton of options, I just saw they even have "deployer" now, which makes things even easier.

What I am looking for:

- with one command, deploying my project to the server (using git). But depending on "deploy dev" or "deploy prod" command, the server needs to know from which branch to pull. So I do need to merge branches before deploying.
- create a new "release" folder on the server and symlink the www folder to the new release.
- keep at least 5 release folders, remove the 5th on every deploy.
- make it possible to rollback, so change symlink to a previous release folder.

I saw I can use Fabric, but it seems kinda complicated and perhaps overkill (like capistrano). I searched quite a lot on the web, but couldn't find a very clear answer/solution. Or a solution which most people agree on.

Any thoughts or people who would like share their experience?

Comment: You can do all of that with `git push` and a CI.

Comment: Ow jeez, haven't thought about that! So you would say, just use `git` commands and circleci for example? Might git hooks work as well...? Might indeed be a better solution, since I might be able to use it for every project and programming language....

Comment: I use circleci but there are plenty of options available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post an answer, cause I see I've been given an answer 9 months ago already, without actually answering the thread.

Like Sayse already told: plenty of ways but GIT and CI are both good ways to implement Continuous Deployment on a VPS.

I've been trying CI, with much success!